# chain starting of programs in bash

Tags: bash, shell

i want to start programs in a chain, like start a bash script startScript.sh and then in the startScript.sh chain load certain programs.

```
startScript.sh
    ./program1 &
     #PID=(echo $!)
     PID=$!
     echo "Wait for 10 seconds here"
     if ps -p $PID > /dev/null; then echo "continue"; ./program2; else echo "PID is not running"; exit; fi
     echo "Wait for 10 seconds here"
     #if program1 is running and program2 is running, then ./program3, else exit.
```

I tried to find the running pid of program1 with $!, but the problem is that program1 is itself a shell script and they invokes further shell scripts in which I am not interested. Hence $! never gives me the pid of ./program1 but something irrelevant. HOw can I get the PID of program1?

Also how can I get the PID of program1 as well as program2 to see if they are running and then start program3.

Comment: Try with `PID=$!`. Right now you are setting `PID` to an array that contains `echo` and your pid (and that doesn't make any sense in this context).

Comment: corrected the error with echo. but still the problem persists. the program1 internally calls further background processes.. So I guess, $! will return me the pid of the further background process and not of program1.

Comment: It doesn't matter if program1 starts more processes, it is itself a process and therefore it's `PID` will be obtainable using `$!`

Comment: `$!` returns the PID of the program most recently put to background *in your current shell/process*. Your `program1` is a different process. `$!` in your script is related only to programs put to bg by itself (currently executing `bash` process).

Comment: You might want to look into `pgrep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special parameter `$!` in shell (from `man bash`):

> Expands to the process ID of the *job most recently placed into the background*, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin (see JOB CONTROL below).

It's important to notice that **job control is shell-local** (in your case local to the `bash` interpreter executing your `startScript.sh`).

That means the `pid` from below:

```
#!/bin/bash
./program.sh
pid=$!
```

will always contain the PID of the `program.sh` script (i.e. the process executing it, defined with a hashbang, in your case probably another `bash` process), regardless of the background processes spawned by that child process (remember that `$!` is local to your script; the `$!` in the child will be undefined, until a background process is spawned there).

---

What maybe sidetracked you initially is the line:

```
PID=(echo $!)
```

that didn't properly set the PID. The `PID` was set to an array containing two words (elements): `echo` and `<pid>`. You want this:

```
pid=$!
```

(and maybe to use lowercase name for the non-global variable `pid`).

---

A simple demo:

```
$ cat script1.sh
#!/bin/bash
./script2.sh &
echo "in script1: $!"

$ cat script2.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "in script2: $!"
sleep 5 &
echo "in script2 after sleep: $!"

$ ./script1.sh
in script1: 19537
in script2: 
in script2 after sleep: 19541
```

Notice how the `$!` in initially undefined in `script2.sh` - if `$!` were to return the last PID *globally*, it would be set to PID of `script2.sh`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. can you also please tell me if the parent program spawns a further backgrounded infinite loop child process, is it possible to find the pid of the child process? I assume, that the parent process cannot die until and unless the child process dies. So if the child process is infinite, then the parent process ( program1.sh ) or even startScript.sh will never die, right?

Comment: If the child process is run in background, parent might exit. To prevent it, use `wait`. You can wait a specific PID with `wait PID`, or if PID is not given (`wait`), it'll wait for *all active children* processes to finish.

Comment: To enumerate all child processes, you'll have to either store them, or later use `ps` (something like: `ps hopid --ppid "$ppid"`).

Comment: great explanation ! so, ./program1 & wait $!; would force an entry into the process table, even if there is exit 0 at the end of the ./program1 !?? assuming ofcourse program1 has an infinite loop  backgrounded child process.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last question, but `./program1 & wait $!` is equivalent to `./program1`. The `./program1` can still spawn background children and exit without `wait`ing them. In that case, the `wait` in the parent will not wait for the grandchildren.

Comment: i will open a new question and give the link here.